# SQL Profiler - Help filter Stored Procs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-profiler

Could someone assist me with the perfect template for using SQL Profiler to debug stored procs? I've tried most templates that are stanard, but all produce a lot of stuff I don't want to see.

I want to start it running, and then see only stored proc related info, such as when it started... when it stops... and that sort of info.

Is there a way to see only that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get just information about when it starts and stops, you need template TSQ_SPs. In this template you need to see the events SP:Starting and SP:Completes. And you can add SQL:Starting, SQL:Completed, SQL:BatchStarting and SQL:BatchCompleted events to find info about non-SP queries.
use filters for process id, as mentioned pkk. But I prefer to use filter for LoginName, because when debugging you will re-create the sessions and SPID will be changed each time.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650699.aspx

I would use `SQLProfilerTSQL_SPs` or `SQLProfilerTSQL` template. 
If this still produces too much output, try filtering by sql process id, which should be easily retrived using `sp_who`.